# Colisiones 2D en pygame

Tags: python, pygame

La colisión ya la tengo por medio de una función de la librería `pygame`. La función devuelve `True` cada vez que se genera una colisión.

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Quiero hacer que cuando una colisión sea `True` no pueda traspasar ese objeto (rectángulo) por otro rectángulo similar a una pared, pero no encuentro el algoritmo correcto.

El código se ve así:

```
if rectangulo.colliderect(recatangulo_2):
    #aqui debe ir el algoritmo que impida 
    #que los objetos se transpasen (como un muro )
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]

Comment: ¿Qué quieres que ocurra cuando haya una colisión? ¿Que ambas figuras "reboten"? ¿Que vuelvan a la posición inmediatamente anterior para que se mantengan sin colisión? ¿Que ambas figuras se queden paradas en la posición más cercana sin que exista colisión? Por cierto, ¿qué tiene que ver `pygame` con `unity`? ¿Puedes borrar la etiqueta para que la gente de Unity no se meta en esta pregunta por error? Gracias.

Comment: Que ambas figuras se queden paradas en la posición más cercana sin que exista colisión ,esto quiero que pase , si sabes alguno algoitmo gracias